# Database Admin Panel inside an ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Its complicated.

I have SQL Server 2008 on my production server and the access to that is restricted using IP. As I don't have a static IP, I cannot connect to server from my machine. The only option is going remote on production server and working there, but for obvious reasons I don't like it.

So the only solution I can think of is using a **SQL Admin Panel** on which I only need to manipulate the table data. The only implementation of this method I saw is one from code project. ( [Link here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETDBAdminControl.aspx) ). Its very outdated and most of the coding is done in classic asp.net style. I do not want to use it.

My questions are

1. Is there a good implementation of SQL Admin Panel in ASP.NET?
2. Have I got any other alternatives on manipulating my IP restricted remote database?

P.S: And yes, I know that maintaining a SQL Admin Panel on a live server is not good at all. I will be removing my SQL Admin Panel from my website as soon as the site goes live :)

Comment: @the person who voted to close: I am looking for a c# implementation that displays the tables with add / edit / delete functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as question 2 is concerned, I have done work on databases sql server 2008 on the host without having a static ip.  My hosting provider put my IP on a safe list which accepted my connection until my IP reset. It's a pain but does stay the same for a long time. You can find yours at http://www.whatismyip.com/

Not sure if your host will allow the same.

Comment: +1: thanks for this. yep. but it changes frequently here. thats the prob. and i cannot ask my client to change the ip from time to time. right now i am implementing my own re-usable db manager :)

Comment: No problems. Not sure as to the nature of your host, but they often also have some admin sections you can go into which also allow direct editing of the database tables.

Comment: That another problem. Its a managed server for which I dont have the cpanel. just the remote access. :)